# Retagging after a product name change (eg, visual-studio-11 to visual-studio-2012)

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

What's the proper protocol for handling retagging of questions when a product's name changed from a code name to a release name?  In particular, I'm asking about [visual-studio-11](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-11) (the pre-release "code name" if you will) becoming branded as [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) after the release of the Release Candidate last week.

Should *all* questions tagged with the now defunct code name be retagged with the new name?  Should *all* questions with the old tag simply be left there, since that tag accurately reflected the name of the product they were asked about?  Or should they be retagged with some amount of thoughtfulness?

Comment: A synonym would be used, not retagging

Comment: Wouldn't you retag the questions with the old tag *then* set up a synonym to the new tag from the old?  I don't think you're suggesting that the old tag should be the canonical tag for this topic.

Comment: you only need 1 question to have the tag before a synonym can be set

Comment: I think I get it now.  I assumed that those questions tagged pre-synonym would linger in obscurity forever.

Comment: I've fiddled about with the tags. visual-studio-2012 is a master tag with visual-studio-11, vs11, vs2011 and vs2012 as synonyms which should catch most variations. If folks want to they can be specific about which version they're having problems with in their questions.

Comment: Thanks @Kev!  I suspect there will need to be some work done on some of the VS products (eg, tfs2012) at some point as well.  (I don't have the rep to do that myself, otherwise I'd help with the housekeeping.)

Comment: Splendid. Let me know what needs done (add to the question and ping me in the comments), I'm not that familiar with TFS, so keep me right.

Comment: we 're trying that between tags "cq5" (old) and "aem" new, but it complains about cq5 being 1.25 times more popular. how is it done then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably Synonym tags are a solution. Read this article : https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

From what I understood from the above article,(if I've understood right) If a new tag is created and the old tag is made a synonym of the new one, the older questions will get retagged to the new tag.