# Visual Studio 11 is now called Visual Studio 2012, what should happen to the tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retagging after a product name change (eg, visual-studio-11 to visual-studio-2012)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134298/retagging-after-a-product-name-change-eg-visual-studio-11-to-visual-studio-201)

During the beta period, Microsoft called the next version of Visual Studio simply "Visual Studio 11."  The tag [visual-studio-11](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-11) was created.

It's now reached Release Candidate status, and they've decided to go back to their yearly theme by calling the product "Visual Studio 2012."  [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) has now come into existence.

The two are effectively the same product, but there are significant changes between Beta and RC.  Should the tags be merged, or should they remain separate?

Comment: My gut feeling is that visual-studio-11 could be made a synonym of visual-studio-2012 for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are they the same product?  They're certainly two stages in the release cycle of the same eventual product, but the two are very different applications.  Problems (and solutions) which applied to the first product don't necessarily apply to the second product.

I imagine the use of the [visual-studio-11](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-11) tag will significantly decline, since pre-release versions of software don't see a lot of use after the actual release.  But it's still a distinct application in and of itself.

I'd suggest that we keep the tag around as-is, and perhaps include it in a general tag cleanup at some point in the future if the questions/answers within it are no longer of value.  But right now, so close after the release of [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012), there's still an install base of [visual-studio-11](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-11) that can benefit from questions/answers.